# How to replace tags in a message with values from another table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, replace, tags

I have 2 tables, one has messages with some tags in the messages that can be replaced with values for specific areas of my system.

The other table contains the tag values.

Is there a way I write a SQL select statement so I can view the message description with tags replaced with the actual values.  Here is an example of my tables

Table 1 - `MessageDescriptions`

```
Id      Description
------------------------------------------------------
1       This message is for <<User.Name>>.       
2       <<User.Name>> uses the currency <<Currency.Code>>.
```

Table 2 - `TagValues`

```
Id      Tags                                               DescriptionId
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
5       [<<User.Name>>:Mr John Smith]                          1
6       [<<User.Name>>:Mr John Smith][<<Currency.Code>>:GBP]   2
```

These tags are stored in the same column in the table which is what is causing me issues. Does anyone know a way I can replace the tag values e.g. Mr John Smith with the tags in the message descriptions?

This is all I have so far, but this only selects the 2 columns from each table. I now need to replace the tags with the tag values:

```
SELECT
    TagValues.Tags, 
    MessageDescriptions.[Description]
FROM 
    TagValues 
INNER JOIN 
    MessageDescriptions ON TagValues.DescriptionId = MessageDescriptions.Id
```

For this example, I would like my output to be:

```
Description
------------------------------------------------------
This message is for Mr John Smith.       
Mr John Smith uses the currency GBP.
```

Comment: Can you please post the output ??

Comment: I'm using SQL Server Management Studio,

Comment: I've added the output I'd like to the bottom of my original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I hope this may help others.  I've managed to find a way, but its not pretty.
Here is the code:

```
DECLARE @EntityId uniqueidentifier = ''

CREATE TABLE #AuditTags
(
    AuditId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    TagField nvarchar(40),
    TagValue nvarchar(300)
)
CREATE TABLE #AuditDetails
(
    [AuditId] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [DateCreated] datetime,
    [Description] nvarchar(max),
    [UserId] uniqueidentifier
)

INSERT INTO #AuditTags (AuditId, TagField, TagValue)
SELECT A.AuditId, Split.a.query('field').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Tag, Split.a.query('value').value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS Value  
 FROM  
 (
     SELECT event_audit_id AS AuditId,  
         CAST ('<doc>' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(tag_value, ':', ''), '|', ''), '<<', '<field>'), '>>', '</field><value>'), '[', '<tag>'), ']', '</value></tag>') + '</doc>' AS XML) AS Data  
     FROM  TagValues
     WHERE [entity_id] = @EntityId
 ) AS A CROSS APPLY Data.nodes ('/doc/tag') AS SPLIT(a);

INSERT INTO #AuditDetails
SELECT event_audit_id, TagValues.date_created, MessageDescriptions.[description], [user_id]
FROM TagValues
INNER JOIN MessageDescriptions ON TagValues.content_template_id = MessageDescriptions.content_template_id 
WHERE TagValues.[entity_id] = @EntityId

DECLARE @AuditId uniqueidentifier, @TagField nvarchar(40), @TagValue nvarchar(300)
DECLARE tag_cursor CURSOR
    FOR SELECT AuditId, TagField, TagValue FROM #AuditTags
OPEN tag_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM tag_cursor INTO @AuditId, @TagField, @TagValue
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    UPDATE #AuditDetails SET [Description] = REPLACE([Description], '<<'+@TagField+'>>', @TagValue) WHERE AuditId = @AuditId

    FETCH NEXT FROM tag_cursor INTO @AuditId, @TagField, @TagValue
END
CLOSE tag_cursor;
DEALLOCATE tag_cursor;

SELECT
AuditId,
DateCreated AS [Date and time],
[Description], 
[User].salutation + ' ' + [User].first_name + ' ' + [User].last_name AS Actioner
FROM #AuditDetails
INNER JOIN [User] ON #AuditDetails.UserId = [User].[user_id]

DROP TABLE #AuditTags
DROP TABLE #AuditDetails
```

Answer (score 0):

may be simply using replace we can achieve this one

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE 
    (Id int, Description varchar(50))
;

INSERT INTO @Table1
    (Id, Description)
VALUES
    (1, 'This message is for <<User.Name>>.'),
    (2, '<<User.Name>> uses the currency <<Currency.Code>>.')
;
DECLARE  @Table2 TABLE 
    (Id int, Tags varchar(52), DescriptionId int)
;

INSERT INTO @Table2
    (Id, Tags, DescriptionId)
VALUES
    (5, '[<<User.Name>>:Mr John Smith]', 1),
    (6, '[<<User.Name>>:Mr John Smith][<<Currency.Code>>:GBP]', 2)
;

SELECT
TagValues.Tags, 
REPLACE(REPLACE(MessageDescriptions.[Description],'<<User.Name>>','Mr John Smith'),'<<Currency.Code>>','GBP')
FROM @Table2 TagValues 
INNER JOIN @Table1 MessageDescriptions ON TagValues.DescriptionId = MessageDescriptions.Id
```

Comment: That would work if they were my only messages and tags, but this table is massive and they aren't my only messages and certainly aren't my only tags.
I have 100s of different messages, all with different tags in them

Comment: okay then we need to work it out using charindex and Substring functions.But you are saying 100's different special characters you have only posted two of them.@Ben

Comment: Well I thought 2 messages would have been enough for an example.
But there are 100s of messages, another could be "<<User.Name>> deleted the attachment <<Attachment.Filename>>"
As you see, there is another tag there for attachments.  And there are many others as well.

Comment: If this isn't possible or isn't easy at all then don't worry about it.  I'll find another way around it.  Maybe a StoredProc would be a better idea for this